# DataBindings in C# , filter in one control affect on data in another control

Tags: c#, bindingsource

I have a static list of data called `Services`. I also have two `BindingSource` objects and this list is bounded to both of them:

```
this.bindingSources1.DataSource = Instance.Services;
this.cbx1.DataSource = this.bindingSources1;
this.bindingSources2.DataSource = Instance.Services;
this.cbx2.DataSource = this.bindingSources2;
```

When I set the `Filter` property in first `BindingSource` object:

```
this.bindingSource1.Filter = " Id = 2 ";
```

in `cbx1` there is only one object but in `cbx2` there are two. How do I set the binding so that setting the `Filter` property in one `BindingSource` does not affect the data source on the second cbx?

Do I have to use `DataSet` and `DataTable`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try set bindingSource to a DataTable and use `DataTable dt=new DataTable();`and use `dt.DefaultView` to make changes this wont affect data on data table

Comment: Ok, but how can I set bindingSource to a DataTable ?

Comment: is this binding source DataSet ?? what is the type of binding source?

Comment: No I don't have DataSet binding source is simply BindingSource, and Instance.Services is collection which implement IList, IBinding, IEnumerable etc. This collection object is created by my. The purpose of Instance.Services is that whenever I add in application new object to this list it is refreshed automatically. When I use DataTable I have to add new row each time when I add new object, and if I have 10 dataTables I have to 10 times add new row to its.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may need to create a new BindingContext for either bindingSources2 or cbx2 (we don't use BindingSources, which is why I am not 100% which one to apply it to).

I would try adding:

```
this.bindingSources2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

immediately before:

```
this.bindingSources2.DataSource = Instance.Services;
```

Comment: No working because bindingSource.Filter modifies Instance.Service and this modifies each bindingSource to it list is assigned

Comment: Can you bind Instance.Service directly to the Combo and implement filtering directly on the rows?

Comment: Yes, I can, but this filtering Instance.Service too

Comment: In that case, I think that your only option is to clone the data that Instance.Service contains into a separate collection/property.

Comment: Yes, I must use Instance.Services.ToList() which create new list of services. End this second collection I can bind to view